# Can I share a MacOS desktop between several user accounts?

Tags: macos, desktop, shared

Can I allow multiple user accounts to open applications directly onto one MacOS desktop?

On X Windows, it's typically about setting DISPLAY and XAUTH. I suspect it's impossible on native MacOS, but it seems worth asking.

I know I can have several users on a single Mac, each running a separate desktop.

I know I can even use ScreenSharing with an SSH tunnel to have those other users' desktops visible on my primary desktop.

The background: I can run (calabash) tests across multiple iOS simulators on one machine at once, each as a different user to provide process/admin separation, each to that user's desktop (using parallel_calabash) but running several desktops wastes machine resources that would be much better spent running more simulators.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but to your suspection: It is possible to run X on OS X, using XQuartz. If the applications you are refering to run under X, you can most likely use this method using DISPLAY and XAUTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer is no.

As of ElCapitan in particular, Apple's security model even makes it difficult/impossible to interact with the desktop from an ssh session to the same user on the same machine, unless you run an sshd from that user's Desktop context such as with a ~/Library/LaunchAgent.

Answer (score -1):

There is a gem you can use. I haven't tried it but it appears they have. Let me know your success.
https://github.com/rajdeepv/parallel_calabash

Comment: Heh, thanks - that's actually the project I'm working on. It uses this multiple user approach, and we want to get away from it.